# WildFly 9.x Deployment Scanner

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-9

I have an application running on Clustered Wildfly environment

Server-One on Machineone and Server-one on Machinetwo are used to form a HA cluster. Serverone also act as a domain controller in my cluster environment.

When I go from UI Console management
http://machineOneIp:9990/console/App.html#domain-deployments

And tries to replace or update the deployment war then it start deploying on both the servers.

Is there any way to change the deployment scanner to stop scanning for new changes ?

Any help would be great use.

Comment: you are updating the deployment but don't want it to deploy? or are you saying you want it to deploy on one server and not the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not the deployment scanner, this scanner is available in standalone mode only and pick up *.?ar from the standalone/deployments folder.

In domain mode a deployment can activated for a server-group.
In this case ALL servers of this group will deploy it.

If you want to have two servers with different deployments you need to create two server groups, you might share the same profile.
But if both are in the same cluster I don't understand why you don't want to have the same application deployed.